# How can I modularize this C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, modularity

I've been working with .NET table adapters and data tables and I've been wrestling with how to modularize this code but I just can't "see" it.
Here's what I have but there's gotta be a way to combine into a one-liner that handles both cases.

```
  class What_I_have
  {
    public void TableAdapterFiller(TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTTableAdapter TableAdapter,
      dsGrids.TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTDataTable DataTable)
    {
      try
      {
        TableAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
      }
      catch (SystemException sex)
      {
        GenericExcHandler(sex, DataTable.TableName);
      }
    }
    public void TableAdapterFiller(TSNKF52_CGFM_USERSTableAdapter TableAdapter,
      dsGrids.TSNKF52_CGFM_USERSDataTable DataTable)
    {
      try
      {
        TableAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
      }
      catch (SystemException sex)
      {
        GenericExcHandler(sex, DataTable.TableName);
      }
    }

  }
```

This is an idea of what I'm trying to do (The type 'HowToTypeThis' presents my quandary):

```
  class What_Id_like
  {
    public void TableAdapterFiller(TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTTableAdapter TableAdapter,
      dsGrids.TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTDataTable DataTable)
    {
      IsolatedMethod(TableAdapter, DataTable);
    }
    public void TableAdapterFiller(TSNKF52_CGFM_USERSTableAdapter TableAdapter,
      dsGrids.TSNKF52_CGFM_USERSDataTable DataTable)
    {
      IsolatedMethod(TableAdapter, DataTable);
    }

    void IsolatedMethod(HowToTypeThis tabAdapter,
      HowToTypeThis DataTable)
    { 
      try
      {
        TableAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
      }
      catch (SystemException sex)
      {
        GenericExcHandler(sex, DataTable.TableName);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: great varible name for that exception. got to give you that.

Comment: @SamOnela LIke I said, it might not be complete enough, and may require more of the code to be shown when posted on CR.  That doesn't make the code hypothetical, as you claim, nor would it make it an inappropriate site for the question to be adapted to, it justs means that a few changes would need to be made; you could have just said *that* instead.

Answer (score 3):

Add interfaces:

```
public interface ITableAdapter 
{ 
  Fill(IdataTable dt);
}
public interface IDataTable { }
```

Update your classes

```
public class TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTTableAdapter : ITableAdapter {}
public class TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTDataTable  : IDataTable {}
```

Write an extension method

```
public static class TableAdapterExtensions
{
  public static void FillWith(this ITableAdapter adapter, IDataTable dataTable)
  {
    try
    {
      adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
    catch(SystemException sex)
    {
      GenericExcHandler(sex, DataTable.TableName);
    }
  }
}
```

Then usage:

```
var ta = new TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTTableAdapter();
var dt = new dsGrids.TSNKF30_STRUCT_ELMNTDataTable();
ta.FillWith(dt);
```